# Cómo setear múltiple datos usando factory en laravel

Tags: laravel, override

tengo unos factories, cuyos modelos son de muchos a muchos, quiero poner datos para hacerlo, pero quiero poner más de un dato del mismo campo

por ejemplo, en el seeder tengo esto

```
    Customer::factory()
        ->hasAttached(Franchise::factory()->count(2))
        ->count(1)
        ->create();
```

me crea 2 `Franchise` relacionadas a un `Customer`, pero ahora tengo este caso

```
    Customer::factory([
        'latitude' => '35.67124282979417',
        'longitude' => '139.76190845496706'
    ])->hasAttached(Franchise::factory([
        'min_distance' => 1000
    ]))
        ->create();
```

estoy haciendo [override](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#overriding-attributes) a los atributos, pero quiero hacerlo (por ejemplo) dos veces para dos Franchise, ambas `Franchise` asociadas al mismo customer

es decir, quiero dos `Franchise`, una que tenga `'min_distance' => 1000` y otra que tenga `'min_distance' => 500`

cómo se puede hacer?

Answer (score 0):

simplemente tenía que volver a usar el método `hasAttached`

```
    Customer::factory([
        'latitude' => '35.67773369679899',
        'longitude' => '139.77640316481111'
    ])->hasAttached(Franchise::factory([
        'min_distance' => 500
    ]))->hasAttached(Franchise::factory([
        'min_distance' => 1000
    ]))->create();
```